# Are there any built-in classes to handle large integer values in C++?

Tags: c++, biginteger

I'm solving some problems on UVA online judge now, and I'm running into scenarios where I have to store very large integer values (15 digits or more sometimes). Is there any way I can do it without the usage of third-party libraries? [Anything similar to `BigInteger` class in java?].

Comment: I did. I was able to find a few posts in SO as well, but I could only find third party implementations of BigIteger, but I'm not sure if I could use it on the online judge.

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12869883/968261) may be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For pow with integers, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring

I would suggest [GMP](http://gmplib.org/)

Please refer this link:- [C++ handling very large integers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/124332/c-handling-very-large-integers)

Answer (score 1):

Third party libraries are needed (unless you feel like writing your own library). GMP or MPIR are the ones to go for.

Answer (score 1):

No, there isn't such structure in standard library. But always you can check out GMP, MPFR or similar. Just search in Google.

Answer (score 1):

You can use GNU's [libgmp](http://gmplib.org/) for arbitrary precision arithmetic in C.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest to use would be Boost Multiprecision

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/multiprecision/doc/html/index.html

Here is a simple example

```
#include <boost/multiprecision/cpp_int.hpp>

using namespace boost::multiprecision;

int main(){

     cpp_int          a_really_big_number("0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF000000000000000");
     a_really_big_number += 7;

}
```